# Is [ʕ] an acceptable allophone for the French R?

Tags: prononciation

My native language is Korean. For me, the French R is too hard to pronounce.

It seems the only uvular consonants that I can easily pronounce are stops, e.g. [q], [ɢ], and [ɴ]. Yet French R is not a stop.

For [ʁ], it's quite hard to place my tongue to make this approximant. It doesn't make a complete oral cavity like a stop, yet it constricts the airflow unlike a vowel. I can't easily match this intermediacy.

For [ʀ], I seem to be *impossible* to make this trill. Whenever I try to pronounce this, epiglottal [ʢ] is made instead.

Yet for strange reasons, it's quite easy to pronounce pharyngeal consonants. So I wonder if a native French would understand my pronunciation if I pronounced the French R as [ʕ]. Would they?

Comment: Do you have an example of language where this epiglottal is used? Or even a sound sample? Is it that one [https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consonne_fricative_%C3%A9piglottale_vois%C3%A9e] ?

Comment: @XouDo Err... Link is broken?

Comment: [this one should work](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consonne_fricative_%C3%A9piglottale_vois%C3%A9e)

Comment: @XouDo [ʕ] and [ʢ] are different consonants. There are few languages that has [ʢ], but according to Wikipedia, it is used in Iraqi Arabic.

Comment: You are refering to [ʢ] also in your question. Anyway, is there a langage using that [ʕ] consonant ?

Comment: @XouDo There are some. Arabic, Danish, Dutch, German, Hebrew, Malay, Somali, and few more.

Comment: Just a note that [ʁ] is a fricative, not an approximant.

Comment: [La consonne /R/ en fle](https://www.verbotonale-phonetique.com/consonne-r-en-fle/) par [Michel Billères](https://www.fun-mooc.fr/fr/contributeurs/michel-billieres/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ʢ] ([wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consonne_fricative_%C3%A9piglottale_vois%C3%A9e)) somewhat sounds like an *R* to my ears. You will certainly be understood, especially if the *R* is the only phoneme with a specific pronunciation of yours. As Pas un clue commented, [ʕ] ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiced_pharyngeal_fricative)) is slightly worse but still good enough as a substitute.

The letter *R* is likely the one with the widest range of realizations in French (including no phoneme at all). It has significantly evolved with time and there are still some regional variants too.

Comment: [This Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiced_pharyngeal_fricative) has the consonant from the question (ʕ). Though ʢ is closer to a French R than ʕ, the latter is still close enough to sound like it should be an R and nothing else when used in French.

Comment: @Pasunclue Tout à fait d'accord.

Answer (score 1):

If you can manage (though that seems unlikely to me if the uvular fricative gives you that much trouble) an alveolar thrill, it would also be recognized as a "r"-sound. [Rhotic consonants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhotic_consonant) are fairly plastic.